# sql query to group columns to avoid replication in d3

Tags: mysql, d3.js

I am using d3 to visualise information from a database on a scatterplot where each dot represents a paper. The x axis is the year and the y axis is the number of citations a paper has. My database has three tables 1) Papers(with columns ID, TITLE, YEAR) 2)Authors(ID, AUTHOR, In_order) 3) Citations(ID_to, ID_from). 
(*where In_order is the order of importance of the author to that paper ie In_order = 1 that author would be the main author listed first).

I am using the tooltip function using data from one of my connections to the database. When I mouseover a dot I want to display in the tooltip the ID, title and the authors of that paper. The query I am using to retrieve this is:

```
SELECT * from `authors` INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, TITLE from papers GROUP BY ID) as addtitle ON authors.ID = addtitle.ID where authors.ID = ".$_GET["paperID"];
```

This returns for example:

```
ID    AUTHOR    In_Order    TITLE    
ID1   AUTHOR1    1          TITLE1
ID1   AUTHOR2    2          TITLE2
```

So what is happening here is it is returning the same info as many times as there are authors where only the AUTHOR and In_order columns are changing.

So when I come to displaying this info in my tooltip:

```
function mouseHandler(d,i){

 d3.json("connection3.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error,data) {
            console.log(d);
                myList = ""
                data.forEach(function(d) {

                    d3.keys(d).forEach(function(key){

                    myList = myList + "<p> "+key+": "+ d[key] +"</p> ";

                    })
                    })

                tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
                tooltip.html(myList)

            })
}
```

The info in turn is replicated twice (for the above example), where the author and In_order info is changed.

```
ID: 1
TITLE: TITLE1
AUTHOR: AUTHOR1
In_order: 1
ID: 1
TITLE: TITLE1
AUTHOR: AUTHOR2
In_order: 2
```

What I want is that the information is displayed only once and after the author heading the list of authors are displayed on the same line and the In_order column doesnt have to come into it as the order that the authors appear on the list will indicate that information.

I know that the output I am getting is because that is what my query returns but I would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on how to alter my query to get the wanted result. Thanks in advance I am new to d3!

Comment: Can't a paper have multiple authors, and an author multiple papers?  It looks like the primary key of your papers table is also the author id.  How are authors linked to papers in the database?

Comment: @primehunter326 yes papers can have multiple authors and authors can author multiple papers. Author ID is equal to papers ID. I just want to retrieve the data so when I display it in the tooltip the info isnt replicated and the authors for a selected paper appear on the same line, is that possible do you think?